# = и <- в языке R

Tags: r, синтаксис

Чем принципиально отличается обозначение `=` и `<-` при, например, присвоении переменной в языке R.

Насколько я знаю по гайду из той же вики разницы технически нет. Тогда почему все используют неудобную `<-`  ? Это традиция?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/assignOps) по операторам в R, кроме `<-` и `=`, есть аналогичный `<<-`:

```
v1 <- c(3,1,TRUE,2+3i)
v2 <<- c(3,1,TRUE,2+3i)
v3 = c(3,1,TRUE,2+3i)
print(v1)
print(v2)
print(v3)
```

Результат:

```
[1] 3+0i 1+0i 1+0i 2+3i
[1] 3+0i 1+0i 1+0i 2+3i
[1] 3+0i 1+0i 1+0i 2+3i
```

---

Причем, в отличии от оператора `=`, операторы `<-` и `<<-` имеют обратную форму записи: `->` и `->>`:

```
c(3,1,TRUE,2+3i) -> v1
c(3,1,TRUE,2+3i) ->> v2 
print(v1)
print(v2)
```

Результат:

```
[1] 3+0i 1+0i 1+0i 2+3i
[1] 3+0i 1+0i 1+0i 2+3i
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что это **ответ** на заданный вопрос?

Comment: Единственное во что я уверен -- документация :)

Comment: раз уж исправляли, стоило ссылку обновить, а то текущая не работает. вот [для последней версии](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/assignOps). там, кстати, чётко указана разница в работе разных операторов присваивания, и, в частности, что оператор `=` имеет очень ограниченную область применения.

Answer (score 4):

В ранних версиях R использовался только оператор <-. Поэтому действительно традиция

Answer (score 0):

Прошерстил от и до документацию и ролики англоязычных коллег - скажем так, ответ дали выше.

Это действительно традиция, довольно приятная эстетически и часто сопровождается словесной игрой, эту стрелку каждый западный пользователь называет по своему и она в какой-то мере стала культовой для языка R.

Можно сказать, без этой стрелки R был бы как JS без всеми "любимых" скобочек для написания скриптов или питон без ИИ, основанного на if-ах.

Comment: ваш ответ не добавляет ничего нового к уже существующим.